# C++ macros #define x

Tags: c++, macros

When you type #define x , you see that no value was assigned to that macro variable. so would that making it a null variable? would that mean it would replace all "x" by a null value? Or would that mean the variable x would be undeclared and stops existing? what would be the purpose of doing that anyways?

```
 #ifndef COURSE_H
 #define COURSE_H
 #endif
```

Comment: It's not a variable. It's a macro. Its replacement list is empty; it would be replaced by nothing.

Comment: @Igor Tandetnik okay but what would be the purpose of that?

Comment: E.g. a conditional compilation could define a macro to something sometimes, and to nothing other times. Say, `#define OVERRIDE override` for those compilers that support the newer keyword, and `#define OVERRIDE` for those that don't. Now you can write `class Base { virtual void f(); }; class Derived : public Base { void f() OVERRIDE; }` and it'll work with both compilers.

Comment: Or, the macro could be meant to be used as a boolean flag with `#if defined(x)`, and not in macro replacement. In this case, just the fact that it's defined matters, but not what it's defined as.

Comment: A practical example: GCC has a compiler-specific [`__attribute__` syntax](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Attribute-Syntax.html), carefully designed so that `#define __attribute__(x)` would define it away, and allow the code to work with compilers that don't support this feature.

Comment: @Igor Tandetnik I have no idea what you mean by 'newer keyword'. Also I don't know what class base or derived are.

Comment: Keyword [`override`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/override) was introduced with C++11, and is not supported by older compilers.

Comment: @Igor Tandetnik I added the broader context to my original question

Comment: That's likely an [include guard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard). It's an example of the macro defined solely for the purpose of being later checked with `#ifdef` or similar.

Comment: @Igor Tandetnik that makes no sense because if they wanna check if it was included before, they'll use #ifdef instead of #ifndef.

Comment: They want to check if it was **not** included before. They would want to compile the contents of the header if the macro is **not** defined (the header was not previously included), and skip it if the macro **is** defined (the header was in fact previously included).

Comment: @Igor Tandetnik if it was NOT defined previously,  then why would they define it to be a 'null value' right now?

Comment: So that the next time the same header is included, it could discover that the macro is already defined, and skip the contents. So that the actual classes and such don't end up defined twice. Again, the actual value of the macro doesn't matter for this case; only its existence is being checked. `#define COURSE_H whatever` would have worked just as well

Comment: @Igor Tandetnik oh I see. thank you for the explanation.

Comment: as igor said this is a header file template definition  you can find it explained in all programming books i believe and heres free link https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/19-header-files/